# Streaming Website

Tags: streaming

I'm not confident that this is the correct place to post this type of question but I haven't gotten many answers looking elsewhere, so apologies in advance.

I've been tasked with setting up the security cameras (approx. 14) at a facility my employer owns. The cameras are all IP cameras that deliver RTMP streams. The desired functionality is to have a single computer for the security cameras that will both record videos and host a website accessible from our virtual network, which would have streams of all our security cameras.

This would be a relatively straightforward task, except that the bandwidth of the plant is known to be limited. We simply couldn't have 14 streams outgoing. I doubt we could sustain more than 2 or 3 without serious hiccups.

The current plan is to set up an NGINX server, have it take in all the streams, multiplex them into a single stream, and then host that on the website.

Is there a better way to go about this? I'm really struggling with this and was hoping there would be an alternative possibility.

Comment: Frankly, when it comes to security cameras, buy a solution designed for this with an exportable format admissible in your legal jurisdiction. Many courts won't admit video as evidence unless it is stored and exported in certain ways (to prevent falsification/tampering). In any case, this question seems to be more related to applications and how they functions rather than a question about networks, even if they do use a network. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

A single multiplexed stream of 14 streams would still require the same bandwidth as the 14 separate streams.

It may be possible to reduce the frame rate and/or other parameters of the camera. Panasonic had a good presentation showing a school hallway full of people, and demonstrated how a frame rate as low as 7.5 fps is still useful.

The real solution is to size the bandwidth to meet the needs of the network.